# How to selectively retrieve specific and nearby rows from a file using a reference list?

Tags: awk, grep

I have two table arrays, here's file A:

```
k1 A 1
k1 A 2
k1 B 1
k1 B 2
k1 B 3
k1 B 4
k1 B 5
k1 B 6
k1 B 7
k1 B 8
k1 B 9
k1 V 1
k1 V 2
k1 V 3
k1 V 4
k1 V 5
k1 V 6
k1 S 1
k1 S 2
```

And a subset of first array (say file B):

```
k1 A 2
k1 B 5
k1 V 2
k1 S 1
```

I want to selectively retain rows in file B from file A and extract nearby rows +/- 3 according to values in column 3.

My expected output is:

```
k1 A 1
k1 A 2
k1 B 2
k1 B 3
k1 B 4
k1 B 5
k1 B 6
k1 B 7
k1 B 8
k1 V 1
k1 V 2
k1 V 3
k1 V 4
k1 V 5
k1 S 1
k1 S 2
```

Any suggestions on how it could be achieved? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What do you mean with: _I want to selectively retain rows in file B from file A and extract nearby rows +/- 3 **according to values in column 3**._

Comment: You talk about having `table arrays` but then tell us the input is actually `files`. Is your input actually stored in shell arrays or awk arrays or files or something else? If the input's simply files - why do you mention and what do you mean by `table arrays`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk one-liner does the job:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2}
    NR==FNR{a[k]=$3;next}a[k]>=$3-3 && a[k]<=$3+3' B A
```

For the given input example (A & B), it will give you the expected output.

The logic is also straightforward, if you know the awk syntax, you should understand it. The codes explain itself.

P.S.
You tagged the question with `grep` as well, but grep is not the right tool to do it.